# Shared Variables Between Repeated Calls

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, so I'm wrote a linked list implementation with some basic utilities. My insert function takes in a node pointer and iterates to the end of the list to append a newly initialized `Node` object, p. To my suprise, repeated calls to the `insert` method appear to share node `p`!? Thus after many invocations, `insert` will assign `p->next` to itself, inducing an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    Node *next; 
    int val;
};

void insert(Node *n, int val) {
    Node * cur = n;
    while (cur->next) {
        cout << "Val " << cur->val << "\n";
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    Node p = {0, val};
    cur->next = &p;
}

int main() {
    Node n1;
    n1.val = 1;
    insert(&n1, 2);
    insert(&n1, 3);
    insert(&n1, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

I ran this through gdb to look at what is going on in insert. Indeed, in the second call to `insert` I found that `p` was already initialized before executing `Node p = {0, val};` and that future calls preserved the *same* value of `p->next` despite explicitly setting it to 0. I seem to have a gap in my understanding because translating this into C produces the same bug. I was only able to fix with malloc which is not what I want.

Why does it occur? `p` is allocated onto the stack per invocation no?

Comment: `p` is allocated on the stack. To allocate it on the heap use `Node* p  = new Node();`. It is needed to be allocated on the heap to keep it, as the stack is deallocated when leaving the function.

Comment: You have undefined behavior because  the instance of `p` no longer exists once you leave the scope of `insert`.

Comment: I see. When the call links 1->2, the stack deallocates p and thus the link between 1->2 is broken right? When insert is called again, it writes on the *same* frame which creates a warped situation where 1->2 (val 3)->3 (val 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `insert` function returns, local variables `cur` and `p` are destroyed and that memory space is available for reuse. You are not allowed to access a variable after it is destroyed, not even with a pointer, because the memory space can be reused for something else. The compiler isn't smart enough to stop you from doing it anyway.

As you see this is not just a theoretical possibility but actually happens, all the time. If you just call the exact same function again it's quite likely that you'll get the exact same memory arrangement so the variable `p` the second time will use the exact same memory space it used the first time. If you call a different function like `printf` (or `cout <<`) instead of `insert`, you might find that space is overwritten with some of the variables inside `printf`.

This is why every single linked list tutorial tells you to use `malloc`. Apart from global variables, it's basically the only way to create some variable that *isn't* deleted when the function returns. A "variable" created by `malloc` isn't ever deleted until you `free` it. (It also has no name, so pointers are the only way to use that variable and this fact seems to confuse many people.)

Comment: Slightly misleading perhaps to say "you're not allowed to access a variable after it's destroyed". The fact that the compiler doesn't stop you is a huge source of problems for C++ programmers. However, the behavior when doing so is undefined, so while it's allowed, the behavior of the program once you do is undefined, and thus such code should be avoided.

Comment: @Chris I added a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

@user53751 is quite correct that your problems derive from variable lifetime  issues. However, `malloc` and `free` are not the proper *C++* tools to use to achieve dynamically allocated memory. Rather you should use `new` and `delete` for this purpose, especially as they not only allocate the correct size memory for the object, but also run the default constructor, or as I've written it below, initialize the `next` pointer to `nullptr`.

You may also wish to make `insert` a member function of `Node` as C++ will allow you to do so.

```
struct Node {
    Node *next = nullptr; 
    int val;

    void insert(int val) {
        Node *temp;
        for (temp = this; temp->next; temp = temp->next);

        temp->next = new Node;
        temp->next->val = val;
    }
};

int main() {
    Node *a = new Node;
    a->val = 1;
    
    a->insert(2);
    a->insert(3);

    for (Node *temp = a; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        std::cout << temp->val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It would also be advisable to define a destructor so you can easily clean up your dynamically allocated memory. *Shown in a simple, naive recursive fashion for demonstration purposes.*

```
struct Node {
    Node *next = nullptr; 
    int val;

    void insert(int val) {
        Node *temp;
        for (temp = this; temp->next; temp = temp->next);

        temp->next = new Node;
        temp->next->val = val;
    }

    ~Node() {
        if (next) delete next;
    }
};
```